# sudo disable trimforce doesn't work

Tags: macos, high-sierra, startup, trim

Since upgrading to High Sierra my boot time slowed down considerably (from ~10 seconds to 90 seconds). Googling this problem suggests disabling Trim might work as a solution, which you do via the `sudo trimforce disable` command, but it doesn't actually seem to disable Trim.

After running `sudo trimforce disable` and pressing `y` twice, my Mac automatically reboots but after rebooting, `system_profiler SPSerialATADataType | grep 'TRIM' or System Information->SATA/SATA Express` still shows `TRIM Support: Yes`

I also tried to disable System Integrity Protection before disabling Trim, and that doesn't seem to work either.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: I am leery that disabling TRIM will increase performance.  TRIM is only a subset of AT commands used by the drive to *mark deleted blocks as such and return either random data or zeros when a read request is sent.*  Before embarking on this, I would try starting with a fresh install (*wipe* the drive, then install clean).  As always, make a full backup before proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

Other users have also reported the same issue. TRIM may not actually be disabled on macOS even if forced. In my testing on a 3rd-party SSD, I could never disable TRIM on High Sierra.

On another note, it might be *possible* to improve your boot performance by following a [guide](https://egpu.io/forums/mac-setup/potentially-improve-macos-boot-performance/) I posted back when I was having similar issues.

The gist of it is that *re-blessing* the boot partition, and resetting SMC+NVRAM may improve boot performance. To *re-bless*, simply go to **System Preferences > Startup Disk**, select the desired boot partition, and restart from there.

Comment: If you find an error in a post, please correct it by editing it instead of pointing it out. Also, link-only answers should be avoided as they will become useless if the linked page goes down. Please summarize the relevant content directly into your answer instead.

Comment: @nohillside Thank you for the pointers. Will keep this in mind for future posts. I have a question though - If I come across a question asking - is this command correct/what's the correct command...? - then would it be appropriate to edit the command in the question itself or should it be a separate answer (as I had done here)? Sounds like in such a case the latter might be better.

Comment: Of course, in such situations an answer is the right way to go :-)

Comment: Unfortunately following your guide didn't work for me. When booting up my Apple icon actually shows up pretty quickly, but the slow part of the boot is after I input my password to my username, where it gets stuck on the progress bar at about 70-75%% for about 1 minute before the boot finishes.

Comment: @Monado Reset SMC again in this stage. Could resolve it.